# replace first of &nbsp; sequence with space character

Tags: python, html, text

I have a HTML formatted text string from an earlier text processing step. It goes like this, and you see that *any* `<SPACE>` character has been replaced by a `&nbsp;` sequence:

`...this&nbsp;is&nbsp;some&nbsp;text&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;and&nbsp;some&nbsp;further&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text...`

Now, I want to replace *some* of the `&nbsp;` sequences within the text with a `<SPACE>` character. The rules would be:

- replace **any single** `&nbsp;` sequence with a single `<SPACE>` character
- replace **the first** `&nbsp;` sequence within a series of `&nbsp;` sequences with a single `<SPACE>` character

The resulting string should then look like this:

`...this is some text &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;and some further &nbsp;&nbsp;text...`

Any ideas for a programmatical approach using Python?

Comment: show us your code so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be shortened to *replace every `&nbsp;` which does not come immediately after another `&nbsp;`*.

To implement this strategy, use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) with a negative lookbehind like so:

```
import re

s = '...this&nbsp;is&nbsp;some&nbsp;text&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;\
     and&nbsp;some&nbsp;further&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;text...'

print(re.sub(r'(?<!&nbsp;)&nbsp;', ' ', s))
# ...this is some text &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;and some further &nbsp;&nbsp;text...
```